# Tree to show 4 levels salesforce

Tags: apex

I am working on one requirement of creating a tree that can show upto 4 levels, I have achieved for 2 levels but don't know how to proceed further here.

I created 3 objects
1) Action_Item__c
2) Test__c
3)Test_Result__c

Test result is having lookup to test and test is having lookup to action item, so in tree for action item I want to show all related test__c records.
I did for action item which is having self lookup.
Can anyone help me out in this please.
My code is below.
Apex Class:

```
public class accconhierarchy {
Private list<Action_Item__c> acc;

public List<accountWrap> accountList { get; set; }
public accconhierarchy (){
    List<contactWrap> cw;
    accountList = new List<accountWrap>();
    acc = [select id,name,Priority__c,Hours_act__c,Due_Date__c,(select id,name,Priority__c,Hours_act__c,Due_Date__c from Related_Action_Items__r) from Action_Item__c limit 500];
    for(Action_Item__c a:acc){
        cw = new list<contactWrap>();
        For(Action_Item__c co : a.Related_Action_Items__r){
           cw.add(new contactWrap(co));
        }
        accountList.add(new accountWrap(a,false,cw));
    }
}

public class accountWrap{
    public Action_Item__c oAccount{get;set;}
    public boolean isSelected{get;set;}
    public List<contactWrap> contactset{get;set;}
    public accountWrap(Action_Item__c a,boolean b, List<contactWrap> c){
        oAccount=a;
        isSelected=b;
        contactset =c;            
    }
}

public class contactWrap{
    public Action_Item__c oContact{get;set;}
    public boolean isSelected{get;set;}        
    public contactWrap(Action_Item__c a){
        oContact=a;
        isSelected=false;                       
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question, you have a four node tree where each node is an sObject and descendant of each other. So it would look like this, right? `First -< Second -< Third -< Fourth.`  If that's the case, I think this wrapper class does the trick.

```
  public class Wrapper{
    public First firstLevel;
    public List<Second> secondLevel;
    public Map<Id, List<Third>> secondId2ThirdLevel;

}
```

The `firstLevel` member variable contains a reference to the firstLevel object, and a inner list to all of it's children. The `secondLevel` is a helper, and is a reference to the second level children. The `secondId2ThirdLevel` is an id from the second level sObject, and a List of it's third Level children. Each of the third level children has a inner list pointing to the fourth and final level.

Here is the structure of the method to get the data:

```
  public static Wrapper retrieveFourLevelData(Id firstLevelId){

    //get data
    First firstLevelRec = [
        SELECT  Id,
            (SELECT Id
            FROM    Second__r)
        FROM    FIRST
        WHERE   Id = :firstLevelId]; 

    Map<Id, List<Third>> secondId2ThirdRecs = new Map<Id, List<Third>>();

    for(First fRec : firstLevelRecs){
        for(Second  sRec : fRec.Second__r){
            secondId2ThirdRecs.put(sRec.Id, new List<Third>);
        }
    }

    for(Third tRec :  [
        SELECT Id, (
            SELECT Id
            FROM Fourth__r),
        FROM Third
        WHERE second_level_parent__c IN :secondId2ThirdRecs.keyset()]){

        secondId2ThirdRecs.get(tRec.second_level_parent__c).add(tRec);
    }

    // construct wrappper
    Wrapper wrap = new Wrapper();
    wrap.firstLevel = firstLevelRec;
    wrap.secondLevel = firstLevelRec.Second__r;
    wrap.secondId2ThirdLevel = secondId2ThirdRecs;

    return wrap;

}
```

So, now that the wrapper class is built out, you can see how you can access each of the level of children:

```
    List<Second> getSecondLevel(Wrapper wrap){
        return wrap.secondLevel;
    }

    List<Third> getThirdLevel(Wrapper wrap){
        return wrap.secondId2ThirdLevel.values();
    }


    List<Fourth> getfourthLevel(Wrapper wrap){
        List<Fourth> allFourths = new List<Fourth>();

        for(List<Third> thirdLevelRecs : secondId2ThirdRecs.values()){
            for(Third tRec : thirdLevelRecs){
                allFourths.addAll(tRec.Fourth__r);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hello @Ohana, thanks for your reply. Can you help me out with vf page.

Comment: Sure. Can you post another question of what you’re trying to do? Also, if this answer works for you please mark it as closed.